# How do I read a value existing inside a Wordpress element and use it in a script?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Wordpress, with Elementor, and for now I can write simple scripts, like a sentence that shows a countdown of whichever length that refreshes every second.
However I'd like to be able to take a value already existing in the page (for example: the price of the product displayed with Woocommerce) and display it on a different button inside the same page, using a script. I know it's a generic question but I don't even know where to start. I don't know if there is a faster way to do it than using a script.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in two ways:

1. Learn how to modify the page template and display data using PHP as follows:

   ```
   <?php
     $product_id = get_the_ID();  
     $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );  
     echo $product->get_sale_price();  
   ?>
   ```
2. Get data using JS in body of the page or by included it another way (only works if you get and display data on the same page):

   ```
   let price = document.getElementById('price');
   let myDisplay = document.querySelector('myDisplay');
   myDisplay.textContent = price.textContent;
   ```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, I tried putting the second code in an HTML element surrounded by the <script></script> tags, in the same page as the checkout (which is displaying a product), but nothing get shown.
I also tried adding 
<p id="demo"></p> 
at the beginning of the code like I did with a countdown script I use and adding
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = price.textContent;
but it still doesn't show anything. I think the script route is the one I should take but I'm kinda new at JS and I'm trying to do all this stuff in a small amount of time.

Comment: To make it work (let price = document.getElementById('price');) you need to make sure that document.getElementById('price') give you right value. Check id or class of element contain price number.